# T4 generation and Wcf proxies generation?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

Hi I am currently in a project there we are consuming some wcf services, but we are not happy with the generation result of the service proxy.

We are getting ugly names like service.NameSpace_Are_In_The_Method_NameBeginSomeMethod.....

And we want the possibility to do some other changes.

Can we somehow change the template that are generating these service client proxies??

I have read something about T4 but everything has been about the objects, which we don't have any problems with cause we are reusing them.